# Golang including local files

Tags: go

I have the following two files:

a.go:

```
package main

func foo() {
    return 42
}
```

b.go:

```
package main

func main() {
    println(foo())
}
```

From what I've learned, it seems as if two files in the same package (and the same directory) should be able to use each other's functions.  Yet, when I run `go run b.go`, I get the following:

```
# command-line-arguments
./b.go:4: undefined: foo
```

What's up?  Do I have to somehow import a.go in my b.go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run using the two files `go run a.go b.go`